# Como hago para pasar un combobox a un int para que se muestre en un Jlabel ya probe con Integer parse pero da error

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que cuando se de aceptar se introduzca la informacion que hay el los tres comboBox en una sola linea

Comment: lo que estas intentando es hacer un cast de un Object a un tipo primitivos por eso  marca error intenta agregar getSelectedItem()`.toString()` o declara la variable `fecha` como `Integer`

Comment: Te sugiero que cambies la imagen que que contiene el código ,  y coloque el código en duro

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes añadir el .toString al final del comobox, tal que así:

```
combo1.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

Te recomendaría que concatenaras la fecha de la siguiente manera antes de pasarla a etiqueta.

```
String fechaCompleta= cboxAño.getSelectedItem().toString() + "-" + cboxMes.getSelectedItem().toString() + "-" + cboxDia.getSelectedItem().toString();
```